Which geometry serializations to include in GeoSPARQL RDF?
I am generating RDF triples for a dataset, and want to support GeoSPARQL. Given a geo:Geometry, multiple geometry serializations can be attached. Some of the options include geo:asGeoJSON, geo:asWKT, and geo:asGML. I believe GeoSPARQL can convert between these different serializations, so it might not be necessary to include all.
Should multiple geometry serializations still be included in the RDF dumps, e.g. for performance? If only one is necessary, which one would be the most performant?

I'd always keep only one serialization in the datasets - as you already mentioned, there are built-in functions to convert in-query on demand. Which one you choose is matter of taste, maybe which tools you're using support which format mostly. we for example stick to WKT. But for e.g. JSON export GeoJSON is indeed another nice option. WKT could in theory support more geometry formats (curves, circles), also WKT does allow for various CRS definitions, in GeoJSON it's WGS84.

Perfomance wise I don't think it matters, indeed WKT/WKB and GeoJSON are more compact than KML/GML. But how large is your dataset? For full Openstreetmap as RDF we use WKT and it works well with all of your tools.

@UninformedUser The dataset currently is not very large, around a 1000 point locations, a few small polygons, and a few pretty large polygons. However, if GeoSPARQL engines have to convert everything to e.g. WKT internally for spatial queries, maybe that would be a better option than GeoJSON.
